# Performance metric

Tags: model-evaluation, rating

Let's say I have two people, A and B, who are each performing a different task. They have an aptitude score which designates how well they perform *any* task; A has apitude score a and B has aptitude score b. A succeeds on her task while the majority of people with an aptitude score equal or higher fail. B fails his task while the majority of people with the same or lower aptitude scores succeed.

Are there any mathematical tools dealing with how to calculate the change of their aptitude scores after this event? I'm looking for something similiar to the Elo rating system that doesn't deal with direct competition (since these players are off doing their own things and not confronting each other).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps if you give more detail you might get more useful replies.  For example, you seem to presume a relationship between the tasks and aptitude.  What is this relationship?  Also, how do you know the relationship between aptitude score and success on the tasks?

Comment: What I'm trying to model is a "career" score. 
Let's say a doctor has been doing his job for five years and that's all we know. We give him a score of 5, which stands for general work experience. We also have an engineer who has 8 yers in the business, so he gets a score of 8. This is also all we know about him.
Now, this doctor manages to diagnose a disease which normaly only doctors with 10+ years of experience could discover in time to start treatment and saves the patient. He performed better than his expected performance. The engineer does the opposite. How would their scores be changed?

Comment: And yes, this model has many flaws in it (perhaps the doctor doesn't have to share computers and therefore manages to search pubmed instead of wasting time moving around books at the library) but I think it looks useful. Any thoughts on improving it would be most welcome, like other ways to calculate the aptitude.

Comment: Number of years in a profession or occupation is not considered a good measure of competence, particularly after the first few years.  Can you find other indicators of competence?  How many professions are you planing to include?  If only a small number, you might be able to invest the time needed to get a good measure for each field of work.  For those new to a field, you might be able to use exam scores.

Comment: Ok, let's say it's exam scores. I'm still looking for a suitable metric but what I really need is to know wether or not equations that can model this even exists.
What I want to do is to give them a score that measures their ability relatively to how difficult it is for other people to perform it.

Comment: So, you would like to predict competence of people based on exam score and task performance.  But the people take different exams and perform different tasks, and both are of unknown difficulty.  Is that correct?  If so, to what end?  Do you want to compare the people in terms of their competence in their respective fields?  If so, perhaps you can try to put the exam scores and the task scores on some common metric and then use a regression equation.  (If you are providing an analogy rather than the situation you are really dealing with, you may be seeing the limitations of using analogies.)

Comment: Let's say it's the exact same test - the SAT for example.
The tasks are not of completely unknown difficulty. You have a given probability to succeed based on how other people with their respective score performed.

Comment: The fields of work, by the way, are many, many thousands and new ones are being constantly added. I do not have the luxury to look through every one of them and try to assess the difficulty, unfortunately.

Comment: If you could estimate the relative importance of the test and the tasks in terms of predicting competence, I think you could standadize the scales, weight the variables, and get a numeric sum that predicts competence.  I do not know why you would want to do that, but it might be possible.  Why do you want to compare the competence of people in different fields?

Comment: When you say relative importance, do you mean as a "work-factor"? That doctors have the factor 5 and engineers the factor 4, in that the SAT is a better predictor of how good a doctor you are? So, a 1200 on the SAT is 6000 as a doctor and 4800 as an engineer? And would the variables be stocastic variables representing the outcome of the task? I'm still somewhat of a n00b in mathematical modelling so I just want to get the jargon straight. :-)
I would like to see if I could design a better wage system, where people are really payed regarding how hard their daily tasks are.

Comment: When I say relative importance of test and task scores, I mean which do you think is the better predictor of competence.  This, in turn, will drive the weight of the factor in the prediction equation.  BTW, usually compensation is based largely on factors independent of job performance, such as degrees required, number of people supervised, budget controlled, supply/demand, etc.  Difficulty of daily tasks is a minor factor in setting compensation.

Comment: Yes, compensation is often independent of the task difficulty since it's already assumed a doctor has harder tasks than nurses. Similiarly, if a nurse is a supervisor and is the only one with that kind of experience in the area, market factors will raise the salary. But, if you have the exact same position as someone else, with the exact same degree and job experience and he messes up while you do extraordinarily good I want to give you a mathematical tool to bring to the negotiation table. If possible, I want the lone doctor be able to check how she matches up against the nurses raises.

Comment: Since I am an industrial psychologist and have studied compensation systems, permit me to make a suggestion.  You might have more success within occupation than across occupation.  If you have the option, you might choose the most populous occupation (or the occupation that you know most about, or the occupation that you think will work best) and develop a tool for it.  Gluck.